# LegendMarkerSize not recognized in ListPlot for Mathematica 10

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm trying to put a legend on a plot done using ListPlot

```
a = Table[i^2, {i, 0, 1, 0.01}];
b = Table[i^3, {i, 0, 1, 0.01}];
ListPlot[{a, b}, PlotLegends -> {"test", "test"}]
```

I can increase the size of the text in the legend using `PlotLegends->Style["legend entry",Fontsize->18]` but I can't make the markers in the legend larger, I've tried `LegendMarkerSize` but the command is not recognized in Mathematica 10 (Student Edition) and I get an unkwown option error.

Comment: does `ListPlot[{a, b}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 6}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  PointLegend[{"test", "test"}, LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, 16}]]` work? Change 16 to a different number to play with the size of markers.

Comment: Thanks, adding the PointLegend worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListPlot[{a, b}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Tiny}, 
  PlotLegends ->  PointLegend[{"test", "test"}, LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, 24}]]
```

[image]

You can also use

```
 ListPlot[{a, b}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{"test", "test"}, LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 20}, 
   BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 20]]
```

[image]